# VSCode: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: visual-studio-code

I followed the Docs of 'https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac'
In the form step exist no error, but when i chose Run > Add Configuration... and then choose C++ (GDB/LLDB), error exists"Cannot read property"
it's a step to edit launch.json file

Answer (score 0):

I also got this on Windows using WSL with a Debian host. I think there is a bug, but it's easy to overcome.

Create a new launch.json file under the .vscode directory by right-clicking and selecting 'new file.'

Paste in the launch.json contents from this page: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl

Make sure that 'preLaunchTask' matches your build task name from tasks.json, that you have the appropriate debugger installed, etc.

It should now work.